# Object property being read as undefined even though the object lists it as set

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-widget-factory

I have a JS Widget that is used to work out the closest location to a users current location from a list (using lat/long).

First of all I use the `_create()` method tries to set the users location by calling `setLocation()` method, and then after that there is a check to see if the coordinates were successfully set before continuing.  Here is the `setLocation()` method, which generates no errors but doesn't result in my proceeding beyond the aforementioned check (`if(typeof(this.coords) != 'undefined')`) -

```
/**
 * Set the users current loction (latitude and longitude)
 */
setLocation : function(){

    var t = this;   // This object

    if(navigator.geolocation){  // Ensure that the users location is available

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){    // Set the users current location within this object
            t.coords = {
                latitude:   position.coords.latitude,
                longitude:  position.coords.longitude
            };
        });

    }

}, // getLocation
```

The curious thing however is that when I `console.log(this)`, `this.coords` is correctly set as an object. However, `console.log(this.coords)` results in **undefined** being output.

Is anyone able to help me understand why this behavior is occurring?

I've listed my full code in this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iZ7eSVtW), and as an example here is how your could test the code -

```
$('#closest').closest({
    stations:   new Array(
        {
            "name": "Exeter St David's",
            "code": "EXD",
            "link": "neveryoumindEXD.html",
            "latitude": "50.729342",
            "longitude": "-3.543290"
        },
        {
            "name": "Swindon (Wilts)",
            "code": "SWI",
            "link": "neveryoumindSWI.html",
            "latitude": "51.566828",
            "longitude": "-1.785450"
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: Given that you're doing `var t = this`, can I assume that `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous?  In that case, you're probably using the results before they're actually known, and the concepts in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) are relevant

Comment: From what I can tell through the docs, the `getCurrentPosition()` is not asynchronous. I think the problem is that I'm setting `t.coords`, which isn't actually `this`.  I've tried `this.coords = t.coords`, but that also failed.